# How do I perform multiple action on RecyclerView item click?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What is the best way to show multiple actions which can be performed on recyclerview item? In my case, I have to perform 5 different actions.

Comment: which kind of actions do you want to perform on recyclerview item click?

Comment: Well, I want the user to perform multiple actions like Edit, Quick Edit, View Analytics, Copy Link and a price calculator.

Comment: with buttons and set onClickListeners ?

Comment: Hi Badran thanks, but i wanted to know UI point of view I mean the way to show the actions. Should i use pop up menu or some other design.

Comment: @PatheticProgrammer oh okay , check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do a beautiful design in recycler view items that has different actions using swipe layout , check out this library on github :

[Android Swipe Layout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout)

[How To Implement (Docs)](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/wiki/usage)

Answer (score 0):

*You can simply create OptionMenu on click on the RecyclerView* 
Below is a complete solution of your question 
[www.simplifiedcoding.net/create-options-menu-recyclerview-item-tutorial/](http://www.simplifiedcoding.net/create-options-menu-recyclerview-item-tutorial/)